# how to sort very large numbers

Tags: c

how to sort very large numbers like

```
03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 
03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142
```

in C

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the question? What are you having trouble with? What do you want the output to be?

Comment: How are you storing the numbers? Or have you not worked that out yet?

Comment: i just want all the six lines to be in the ascending order(i.e.)sort the six lines..

Comment: okay how did you select his solution so quickly without even explaining what @DavidSchwartz asked? I suspect `user1487765` and `nims` are working together

Comment: @Subs Suit yourself, i just found this question exactly similar to a SPOJ problem i had solved earlier and i just posted that solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar SPOJ question
http://www.spoj.pl/problems/SBANK/

You can either solve it with `Radix sort` or simply by `Binary Search Tree`(I did it that way).

Here is how you will do in C++ (implement your own `std::map` / `std::set` / `binary search tree` in C)

```
    map<string,int> tab;
    map<string,int>::iterator it;
    char acc[40];
    int n;
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        gets(acc);
        tab[acc]++;
    }
    for(it=tab.begin();it!=tab.end();it++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n",it->first.c_str(),it->second);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

My above program also prints the count of equal numbers, which i don't think is specified in your question. So, in that case, a simple std::set or a straightforward binary search tree will also work. Although in the above question, i could have solved with std::set instead of std::map much easily.

Comment: You can also get yourself into a bigint library, like GNU GMP :)

Comment: @H2CO3 That is also a solution, but i doubt if it would be efficient. As in that SPOJ question, i used my bigint library, and my solution exceeded the time limit.

Comment: i got it accepted with this solution..

Comment: @nims But by this method does 10 not come before 3?